# XSL-FO url function into a template

Tags: url, xslt, xsl-fo, param

I'm using Apache FOP Version 1.1 to build a pdf (by command line)
Here is my XSL that's working fine

```
<fo:table-row >
    <fo:table-cell >
        <fo:block >
            <fo:external-graphic content-height="9mm" content-width="9mm" height="10mm" width="10mm" scaling="non-uniform" src="url(./images/pict2.jpg)" />
        </fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row >
```

If I try to use a template declared in this way

```
<xsl:template name="myRow" >
    <xsl:param name="imgUrl"/>
    <fo:table-row >
        <fo:table-cell >
            <fo:block >
                <fo:external-graphic content-height="9mm" content-width="9mm" height="10mm" width="10mm" scaling="non-uniform" src="url($imgUrl)"/>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row >
</xsl:template>
```

and I call it as

```
<xsl:call-template name="myRow">
    <xsl:with-param name="imgUrl" select="'./images/pict2.jpg'" />
</xsl:call-template>
```

no image is shown.
If I write select="./images/pict2.jpg" (without single quotes) the imgUrl parameter is null
How can I pass the url and get it working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to refer to a variable in an attribute you need to use Attribute Value Templates.

Try this line instead in your template

```
<fo:external-graphic content-height="9mm" content-width="9mm" height="10mm" width="10mm" 
                     scaling="non-uniform" src="url({$imgUrl})"/>
```

The curly braces indicate an expression to be evaluated, rather than output literally (which is what is happening to your code at the moment. It is literally outputting the text **$imgUrl**, rather than the value of the variable).